# Is this a bad practice for droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever a user presses a div button I want to register a droppable. I'm setting a the closure
`add.droppable({})` to the `var toDrop` and then invoking methods on `toDrop` as below, is this a bad practice ?

For example instead of `toDrop.addClass("newColors");` should I be using something like

```
this.addClass("newColors")
```

Here is the complete snippet :

```
$("#myDiv").on('click' , '.colors' , function() { 
    var add = $(this).parent();
        var toDrop = add.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
            toDrop.addClass("newColors");
            toDrop.attr("portletName", parameter);
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I think it hinders the readability a little bit. Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I don't, thats why I asked for a better way :)

Comment: Right on. Shankar's got you covered then. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to use that variable `tpDrop` other than in the drop handler it is advisable to use `this` keyword instead of a creating a closure which represents the droppable element.

So you should be using `$(this).addClass("newColors");`

You can make use of jQuery chaining feature.

`$(this).addClass("newColors").attr("portletName", parameter);`